# re-rendering React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have a react class in which I need to use `shouldComponentUpdate()`, to prevent an infinite loop between the component and its parent.

I simply check whether a deep clone of `nextProps` is equal to `this.props`, and I only update the component if they're not.

So far, so good. (?)

```
class Child extends Component {
  onComponentUpdate = (e) => {
    this.props.update(e)
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return  JSON.stringify(nextProps) !== JSON.stringify(this.props)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        // some code that might trigger onComponentUpdate()
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, in my parent component, something happens that makes me want to re-render the child, without specific props changing. What I did now, is changing a counter in state and passing it to the child as a prop. I never do anything with the counter itself, it is merely an indication for the child that props actually changed so that the child should update.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { counter: 0 }
  }
  otherChildChanged = () => {
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child
          counter={this.state.counter}
          update={"some function"}
          other={"props"}
        >
        </Child>
        <OtherChild onChange={this.otherChildChanged}>
        </OtherChild>
        // some code that might trigger onComponentUpdate()
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Not sure why you want to re-render a child if its props haven't even changed?

Comment: I have a resizable div (Click and drag the border and the div and its neighbour resizes).

Answer (score 0):

You should pass down the size of your resizable div as a prop to the Child Component. This way, when it changes, `JSON.stringify(nextProps) !== JSON.stringify(this.props)` will be `true` and a re-render will occur.

If a component has to behave in a certain way (re-render, for example) depending on something that happens on his Parent, it should be passed to it as a prop.

Comment: I could do that, but my element is resizing with css (styled components). I'm not changing the actual size with javascript. It only needs to know that it needs to update, so it also feels redundant / misleading to send size props if in the end the component doesn't do any logic with that size.